# Chromium browsers showing wrong font in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, fonts, microsoft-edge, chromium, truetype-fonts

On some websites, chromium-based browsers (Edge and Chrome tested) on Windows 11 will display a font that looks exactly like Courier New instead of the correct font. Firefox will display it correctly.

The issue occurs only on a few websites. Browsers are all up-to-date. The substitute font is always a Courier New or a very similar look-alike that misses special characters like 'ç' or 'é', and removing some offending elements from the `font-family` css via inspector seems to work, but it isn't consistent (for instance, `"Roboto"` causes the weird substitution on some sites, but not all, while different and rather common values like `sans-serif` affect other sites).

I noticed a small similarity with some bugs solvable by reinstalling the offending font (it would be Courier New, in my case), but Windows won't let me remove the file, even with Administrator elevation, and not even using Lock Hunter to mark it for deletion on the next boot.

I've also noticed lot's of _0 and _1 suffixed font files in my C:\Windows\Fonts (for instance, cour.ttf, cour_0.ttf). In the end, I discovered that whenever I reinstall and accept a overwrite of these existing, stuck font files, I get these copies suffixed with an index. Thus, reinstalling Courier New seems out of hand for me as a solution.

The most annoying part of this is that my native language is Portuguese, and lots of characters end up being replaced by empty space, and while it ain't impossible to understand, it's becoming increasingly annoying.

Any pointers or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I would perform an in-place upgrade. That should resolve the font corruption

Comment: @Ramhound How does one go from a latest version to an in-place upgrade?

Comment: Use the ISO for the version you have installed